# rtl text in emacs

Tags: emacs, hebrew

I'm using emacs to write my thesis. I need to create a Hebrew abstract. Is there a way to enable right-to-left text display in emacs? (the correct answer should be how can I enable right-to-left text in emacs?)

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature of Emacs 24. Screenshot and discussion [here](http://beresheit.blogspot.com/2010/07/hebrew-and-bidi-text-in-emacs24.html).

Emacs 24 was recently released, but not in time to be included in Ubuntu 12.04. It is already included in development builds of Ubuntu 12.10. Meanwhile, for 12.04 users there is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) for emacs24 which is probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'right-to-left)
```

You may also want to take a look at `toggle-input-method` command.

More info [Bidirectional Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html)